# Copied Canvas Element to iFrame not Rendering

Tags: jquery, iframe, printing, jqplot

Using jquery I am copying the contents of a DIV to a new iFrame I am creating on the fly.  All the elements within the DIV are rendering properly with the exception of CANVAS elements.
The CANVAS elements are being copied, they are just not rendering properly within the iFrame.  Thats the general issue.

Specifically, I am trying to copy the rendered output of a jqPlot chart to an iFrame and then print the chart within the iFrame.

Any ideas why the CANVAS element is not rendering in the iFrame?

Comment: I guess you need to re-run the code that draw on the canvas, on your newly added canvas-element, as it gets added as a blank canvas-element. Not sure though.